# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is the vector space of all real sequences $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. The operations are defined in this manner:

$(x_n)+(y_n):=(x_n+y_n)$ and $\lambda * (x_n):=(\lambda x_n)$.

What are the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of the endomorphism $S: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, given as

$(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mapsto (x_{n+1})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvectors are geometric series: suppose that $(x_n)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and WLOG $x_0=1$. Then
$$[S((x_n))]_k = x_{k+1} = \lambda x_k. $$
By induction, we have $x_{k} = \lambda^k$. Hence $(1,\lambda,\lambda^2,\dotsc)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. It is also the only one up to scaling: the only extra assumption we made was that $x_0=1$, and the eigenvalue equation determined the rest of the vector completely. Lastly, suppose $x_0=0$. But then
$$[S((x_n))]_0 = x_1 = \lambda x_0 = 0,$$
and by induction $x_n=0$ for every $n$.